# Automatized reception of mails in mailbox

Tags: java, email, imap, pop3

Good afternoon,

I would like to control a mailbox (it is an internal mailbox, different than gmail, outlook etc..), and I am using POP3 or IMAP to do it.
Everything it is okay, but right now I am using a scheduler to check the e-mail every X minutes. Is there any option like an event or something (or a library/protocol), to launch a function every time an e-mail it is received/created in one folder of the mailbox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's local, it would be way better to use an SMTP interceptor to run a script on arrival.  You could use this to process the incoming message directly, or to kick off your script.  Otherwise, you can look into IMAP IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as forwarding to a program, or forwarding to a pipe. It was common practice 20-40 years ago. People seem to have forgotten nowadays, [but still ask about it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6571/fnord).

Your program will receive the email on stdin. If you want to process the email, you can parse your input and do... whatever. If you want to control the inbox, you can forward to *both* the inbox and the pipe (the aliases/.forward syntax allows that), discard the input from stdin, and and manipulate the inbox. Your program will be started at the right time to do the manipulation you want.